# get html with lua

Tags: lua

Halo,

I'm trying to make a awesome widget. I would like do download information from a website but I don't know lua and I didn't found anything good on the web.

I would like to pass in a domainname or a IP and get back the html code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://lua-curl.luaforge.net/.

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend using [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/). It is probably included in your system package manager's repositories and if not you can easily get it with [LuaRocks](http://luarocks.org/).

```
$ luarocks install luasocket
$ lua
> require 'luarocks.require'
> http = require 'socket.http'
> html = http.request 'http://www.google.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`webGet`](http://www.strixdb.com/DOC/webGet_doc.html):

```
require('webGet')
cli = webGet.new{}
local address = 'http://www.strixDB.com/samples/animals.rdf'
local rc,error=cli:GET(address, print) -- print the file
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu and other popular Linux distros at least you can get luasocket from your package manager and then use that.

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local page = http.request("http://www.google.com")
```